# Usage of volatile field in CopyOnWrite

Tags: java, concurrency, copy-on-write

The "standard" code of copy on write looks like:

```
...
private volatile SomeClass object;

private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public change (...) {
    lock.lock(); //set lock on write
    try {
        SomeClass newObject  = new SomeClass();
        //do something with new object
        ...
        //set new object
        object = newObject;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock(); //release lock
    }
}

public Object getSomeField () {
    SomeClass obj = object;
    return obj.getSomeField();
}
```

The question:  why the field that keeps reference on "protected on write" object
is volatile? (for example see implementation of CopyOnWriteArrayList).
As far as I know the object reference assignment operation is atomic,
so it looks like there is no need in volatile modifier. Am I wrong here?

Comment: This is needed to provide visibility to other threads. Without `volatile` reference assignment might be visible only to thread that did the change. You wouldn't need it if get method worked under the same lock that is used to change field.

Comment: Thanks! It is the aspect that I didn't take in account

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know the object reference assignment operation is atomic

Yes, but [`volatile` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) is not about the atomic assignment, it's about that value of this variable would be the same for all threads that read this variable.

It's actually about atomic variable access, not about atomic variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

From ["Atomic Access" in the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) (emphasis mine):

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because **any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads**.